# Find a subset of a set that create a balance set of value

Tags: python, algorithm

I know that the title is a bit ambiguity. Please read for more detail.

### Input

I have a known number of sets (like 10000) with variable length, each of them is a subset of the English alphabet. It looks like this:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
b = ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
c = ['x', 'y', 'z']
....

unique_value = set((*a, *b, *c, ...))
# {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', ..., 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'}
```

### What I need

I need to choose a fix number of set (like 100) from those above 10000 set, in which this subset contains all English characters, and the count of each character is **as `balance` as possible**. `balance` mean the character distribution is uniform. I know it's hard to pick a perfectly uniform distribution, so  defining a `balance criteria` is also important.

## My question

1. How to pick the subset (with properties as above) from the original set
2. Definition of a balance criteria

Please suggest me a way to achieve this. Any advice will be gratefully appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The general algorithm I would try would be a probabilistic one. I would create a reverse lookup table from characters to subset_ids, then proceed to add and remove subsets to balance around +0/+1 of the fixed number of subsets. When adding subsets, I'd add a randomly selected subset that contains the least populated letter, and when removing I'd select from the subsets containing the most populated letter. There should also exist a small chance of "mutating" and selecting a completely random subset to add/remove, to prevent being stuck in a local minimum.

I tried to code this solution, but it quickly degraded into some spaghetti code as I fixed edge cases and bugs. Its far from a polished solution, and may even return the wrong answer, but at least it might give you some ideas.

```
# Make lookup table
lookup = defaultdict(set)
for idx, subset in enumerate(subsets):
    for character in subset:
        lookup[character].add(idx)

best_score, best_subsets = 1, None
size = 10 # number of subsets to pick
subset_indices = set() # subset_ids
character_subsets = defaultdict(set) # subset_ids per letter
# loop some large number of times
for _ in range(10000):
    if len(subset_indices) > size: # remove elements
        idx = choice(list(subset_indices)) # maybe pick a random
        if random() < 0.9: # 90% chance pick an existing subset to remove
            indices = max(character_subsets.values(), key=len) # indices to pick from
            idx = choice(list(indices)) # pick one
        for character in subsets[idx]: # remove index/subset_id from lookup
            character_subsets[character].remove(idx)
        subset_indices.remove(idx) # remove subset_id from random draw pool
    else: # add a new subset
        idx = choice(list(set(range(len(subsets))) - subset_indices)) # invert random selection
        if random() < 0.9: # 90% chance to pick a new subset from the min populated
            i, indices = min(character_subsets.items(), key=lambda x:len(x[1]), default=(randint(0, len(lookup)-1),set()))
            indices = lookup[i] - indices # invert
            if not indices: continue # abort if empty
            idx = choice(list(indices)) # pick
        for character in subsets[idx]:
            character_subsets[character].add(idx) # update dict
        subset_indices.add(idx) # update random selection set
    score = pstdev(map(len, character_subsets.values())) # measure distribution
    if score < best_score and len(subset_indices) == size: # if better
        best_subsets = dict(character_subsets) # record it
        best_score = score

# do logic to pretty-print or process best_subset however you like
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. Can you elaborate this part? `When adding subsets, I'd add a randomly selected subset that contains the least populated letter, and when removing I'd select from the subsets containing the most populated letter`

Comment: @enamoria You want to balance the # of occurrences of each letter, so when we add a new subset, we pick one containing the letter with least occurrences. However, to "shuffle" things around a bit hoping it'll settle its way into a global minimum, we also remove a subset (to make room for adding another). This subset that we remove should be one containing the letter with most occurrences, to bring it down and hopefully balance things a bit.

Comment: I drew ideas from [walksat](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~elkan/150/oct25.html) when crafting this algorithm, if that helps give you any intuition behind my reasoning.